# Pandas dataframe describe gives nan value for mean & std for float data type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 8M rows, when I use `df.describe() or np.mean(df[col]) or df[col].mean()` I get `nan` as output.

But, when I check `np.mean(df[col].values)`, It is working. I can able to get the mean value.
There are no `nan` values in that column. I have tested using `df[col].isna().sum() and df[col].isnull().sum()`

Not sure how to reproduce the bug.

Update:

```
>>> df.head()
    col1        col2
0   2.289062    290
1   2.289062    290
2   2.289062    290
3   2.289062    290
4   2.289062    290

>>> df[col1].dtype
dtype('float16')
```

Is there a way to debug or resolve this error?

```
>>> pd.__version__
'1.3.4'
```

Comment: Is it dataframe or series? Can you show the head of dataframe?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi It's a dataframe

Comment: maybe before mean df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce') and after that apply the mean ?

Comment: @ErenHan Not working. Still getting `nan`. Not even getting how to debug this :(

Comment: can you share the head of dataframe

Comment: Did you check the type of `col`? Have you tried `df[col].mean(numeric_only=True)`?

Comment: @Tranbi Got an error `Series.mean does not implement numeric_only`

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I have added head of dataframe to the post.

Comment: @Pythoncoder what is dtype for both column .in your dataframe ????

Comment: @qaiser it's `dtype('float16')`

Comment: Can you try `df[col].astype('float64').mean()`  ?

Comment: Just as a check, if you change the datatype to `'float32'`, does it work?  The CPU can't do math on float16 types.  All it can do is convert to/from float32s.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, it's working even if I convert to `float32`

Comment: Yes, float16 is OK for storage, and it's OK if you are using a GPU, but CPUs can't process it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert column to `float64/float32`, because [`no hardware support for float16 on a typical processor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38977958/2901002):

```
df[col].astype('float64').mean()
df[col].astype('float32').mean()
```

Comment: It's working even if I convert to `float32`. I have converted to lower dtype to optimize the data size. .